# Why does java allow a method which always throws an exception to declare the return type as that exception?

Tags: java, exception

Why does java allow a method which always throws an exception to declare the return type as that exception? 
Both the following methods are valid:-

```
public RuntimeException alwaysFails() {
    throw new RuntimeException("failed");
}

public void alwaysFailsButVoid() {
    throw new RuntimeException("failed");
}
```

What's the benefit of allowing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can declare any type to be the return type of the method. Since the method never returns normally, this is perfectly true (but misleading).

Note that the Java compiler cannot determine for certain when your methods might return normally, in general (due to the Halting Problem being unsolvable).

The benefit of allowing this is to allow you to subclass a class or inherit an interface which has already pre-specified the return type for that method. It's essential for Object-Oriented Programming.

Comment: So if I got it right - a better approach would be to use generics in the method signature, something like: `public <E> E alwaysFails()` ?

Comment: That would be very flexible, but it seems like an odd thing to do.

Comment: LOL writing `alwaysFails()` seems like an odd thing to begin with - but I'm sure somewhere someone will find a good usage...

Comment: alwaysFails() was just for illustration. But Guava Throwables uses this. Look at the implementation of `Throwables#propagate()`. This was the trigger for my question. I am satisfied with the arguments provided by @RobinGreen

Answer (score 5):

Returning and Throwing aren't the same thing and they are independent.

Comment: True, but I don't understand how does it answer the question (the first example).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the issue.  There is no compile time cross check between return types and possible exceptions.  There is no relationship.  The compiler only checks to see what checked exceptions are possible and what exceptions are declared with regards to exceptions (obviously, the compiler does a whole lot more beyond this).